# How to annotate pointer to C character array in method signature?

Tags: python, pointers, annotations, ctypes

I am writing a wrapper for a C library in Python.  I am trying to properly annotate all of the methods, so my IDE can help me catch errors.  I am stuck annotating one method, can you help me figure out the proper annotation?

One of the methods in the C library works as follows:

1. Takes one arg: pointer to a character buffer

   - Buffer is made via: `char_buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)`
2. Populates the char buffer with the output value

   - Done via `CMethod(char_buffer)`

One then parses the buffer by doing something like `char_buffer.value`.

How can I annotate the wrapper method to look for a pointer to a character buffer?  Currently, I have the below, but I think this is incorrect, since `POINTER` seems to be just a function in `_ctypes.py`.

```
from ctypes import POINTER

def wrapped_method(char_buffer: POINTER):
    CMethod(char_buffer)
```

Comment: `char_buffer: POINTER(c_char)` or `char_buffer: c_char_p`?

Comment: @CristiFati using `ipython` I tried the following: `isinstance(create_string_buffer(16), POINTER(c_char))` --> output is `False`, and `isinstance(create_string_buffer(16), c_char_p)` --> output is `False`.  Am I off base?  I think those two may not work

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. It's `ctypes.c_char * 16`. `isinstance(ctypes.create_string_buffer(16), ctypes.c_char * 16)` will return *True*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes.create_string_buffer(init_or_size, size=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.create_string_buffer):

> This function creates a mutable character buffer. The returned object is a ctypes array of [c_char](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_char).

Example:

> ```py
> >>> import ctypes
> >>>
> >>> CharArr16 = ctypes.c_char * 16
> >>> s = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
> >>>
> >>> isinstance(s, CharArr16)
> True
> >>> isinstance(s, ctypes.c_char * 15)
> False
> >>> isinstance(s, ctypes.c_char * 17)
> False
> >>>
> >>> # A more general form, but it WILL FAIL for non array instances
> ...
> >>> isinstance(s, s._type_ * s._length_)
> True
> >>>
> >>> # A more general form that WILL WORK
> ...
> >>> issubclass(CharArr16, ctypes.Array)
> True
> >>> isinstance(s, ctypes.Array)
> True
> ```